# Sustituto de PresentationLink

Tags: ios, swift4

"PresentationLink" no funciona, adjunto el código:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        PresentationLink("Cargar una nueva ContentView", destination: ContentView())


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

El error:

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'PresentationLink'"

Gracias, ¿alguien sabe como adaptar el código a la nueva versión?, ¿ha sido "deprecado"?

Comment: Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo. Una posible es como comenta Erick: -> Sobre poniendo la vista entre las etiquetas ZStack con condicionales. Y otra que se me ocurre es que lo metas dentro de un NavigationView/NavigationLink Saludos,

Comment: Gracias Jesús, ya no es necesario. Es un código que ha sido deprecado, tal y como indicas, actualmente, con NavigationView/NavigationLink se hace correctamente. Gracias por molestarte en contestar y disculpa mi tardanza en contestarte.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle() }){
   Text("Cargar una nueva ContentView") 
}
```